# How to have my main class call repaint from another?

Tags: java, paint

I have a few classes, but the ones I'm using for this question are Main.java and PaintA.java

PaintA has all the paint, obviously in the

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

How can I tell Main.java to repaint that without actually having it paint first?
In main.java I have paintFile as my object.
trying

```
paintFile.repaint(); /* doesn't work and neither will*/
paintFile.paint(g);
```

I would think if this works THEN i could repaint 
but without it how could i?

If it helps, it extends the main class

Comment: Idk if its allowed but.. bump :(

Answer (score 0):

This question is basic, `Main` method is `static` so it can calls evry `method` in `static context`. if your `repaint` method is `static` or it owner class instance is static then `main` method can calls it.
for sample:

```
class PaintA
{
    public void repaint(Graphics g)
    {
        /*
         * do somthings
         */
    }
}
```

then:

```
public class Main
{
    private static PaintA paint = new PaintA();
    public static void main(String[] arg)throws Exception 
    {
        paint.repaint(new Graphics());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm.That solved one problem. Still doesnt work though :\

It calls it fine but it doesnt show up as painted. I think to repaint I would have to paint first, no? And I cant do painter.paint(g);

Comment: I mean when I run it to test nothing shows up but a blank screen as if I had no paint at all. But no errors occur (or any that are shown)

Comment: Do you set visible to true by calling this code: `setVisible(true)`

Comment: This program im trying to write is VERY basic. Its not even using JSwing or whatever you call it. Just regular paint. So no. I tried it anyway, still did nothing.